# VLAN configuration on HP J9279A

Tags: networking, vlan, hp-procurve

I've tried to set up separate VLAN for lab environment on one of my HP switches (J9279A/J9280A).

Network schema:

```
               WAN
                |
                GW
                |
              port1
                |
SW_2---Trk1---SW_1---Trk2---SW_3
```

Subnets:

- 192.168.100.0/24 - vlan 1 - management network, switches, router, etc.
- 192.168.10.0/24 - vlan 2 - user devices
- 192.168.50.0/24 - vlan 3 - iscsi devices
- 10.100.0.0/16 - vlan 100 - lab subnet (that is not working at the moment)

SW_1 config:

```
vlan 1 
   name "Management" 
   forbid 2 
   untagged 1,Trk1-Trk2 
   ip address 192.168.100.240 255.255.255.0 
   no untagged 2-20 
   jumbo 
   ip proxy-arp 
   exit 
vlan 2 
   name "users" 
   forbid 4,6,8,10,12,19-20 
   untagged 2-3,5,7,9,11,13-18 
   ip address 192.168.10.240 255.255.255.0 
   tagged 1,Trk1-Trk2 
   jumbo 
   exit 
vlan 3 
   name "iscsi" 
   forbid 2-3,5,7,9,11,13-18 
   untagged 4,6,8,10,12,19-20 
   tagged 1,Trk1-Trk2 
   jumbo 
   exit 
vlan 100 
   name "10.100" 
   forbid 2-20 
   tagged Trk1-Trk2 
   exit
```

SW_2 config:

```
vlan 1 
   name "Management" 
   forbid 1-22 
   untagged Trk1 
   ip address 192.168.100.241 255.255.255.0 
   no untagged 1-22 
   jumbo 
   exit 
vlan 2 
   name "users" 
   forbid 7-16 
   untagged 1-6,17-22 
   tagged Trk1 
   jumbo 
   exit 
vlan 3 
   name "iscsi" 
   forbid 1-6,8-22 
   untagged 7 
   tagged Trk1 
   jumbo 
   exit 
vlan 100 
   name "10.100" 
   untagged 8-16 
   exit
```

SW_3 config:

```
vlan 1 
   name "Management" 
   forbid 1-46 
   untagged Trk1 
   ip address 192.168.100.242 255.255.255.0 
   no untagged 1-46 
   jumbo 
   ip proxy-arp 
   exit 
vlan 2 
   name "users" 
   untagged 1-35,45-46 
   no ip address 
   tagged Trk1 
   jumbo 
   exit 
vlan 3 
   name "iscsi" 
   forbid 1-6,8-46 
   tagged Trk1 
   jumbo 
   exit 
vlan 100 
   name "10.100" 
   forbid 4-35,37-46 
   untagged 36 
   tagged Trk1 
   exit
```

Device (IBM X3550 M2) is connected to SW_2 on ports 11-12. Interface configuration:

```
auto eth2
iface eth2 inet static
  address 10.100.0.11
  netmask 255.255.0.0

auto eth3
iface eth3 inet static
  address 10.100.0.12
  netmask 255.255.0.0
```

My understanding is, that in current configuration this device should lay in its own, separate network inaccessible from any other VLAN. I've done some testing, and, to my surprise, I am able to connect to this machine.

I've run wireshark to see what's going on, and broadcast ping (ping -b 10.100.255.255) is also received by my PC, that is connected to port 1 in SW_3 (untagged in VLAN 2).

Configuration of interface on my PC:

```
2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 08:00:27:d9:83:4f brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.10.16/24 brd 192.168.10.255 scope global eth0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 10.100.0.2/32 scope global eth0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::a00:27ff:fed9:834f/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

Could anyone explain to me what is going on, and how this should be set up correctly?

Comment: How is that eth2 connected to ports 11 _and_ 12 on the switch?

Comment: Forgot to include it - it has separate connection with another IP address. Fixed.

Comment: Is spanning-tree enabled?

Comment: it is enabled, but it doesn't seem to be STP issue - at least according to logs: `I 01/07/90 01:19:16 ports: port 12 is Blocked by STP
I 01/07/90 01:19:19 ports: port 12 is now on-line
I 01/07/90 01:24:37 ports: port 11 is Blocked by STP
I 01/07/90 01:24:40 ports: port 11 is now on-line`